# Selected item from spinner causes TextView to change automatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview, android-spinner

I followed steps in how to change value of textview according to selected item and here is a piece of the code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){.......

     final TextView privacyTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eventPrivacy);

            privacySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id3) {
                    final String selectedItem =  parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();  
                         privacyTextView.setText(selectedItem);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                }
            });
```

list is :

```
  <string-array name="privacy_levels">
        <item>Everyone</item>
        <item>Friends of Friends</item>
        <item>Friends Only</item>
        <item>Customize</item>
    </string-array>
```

I have text view with value : `privacy` when running app it's automatically changed to `Everyone` -frist one on the list- so what is going wrong ?!!!

Comment: Try this final String selectedItem = privacySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:prompt` in **Spinner** xml and set a name like

```
android:prompt="Privacy";
```

So first time it will show privacy then user can select from the drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...!

final String selectedItem =  parent.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
                     privacyTextView.setText(selectedItem);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get first item as privacy then you need to add another item in your array as **Privacy**.

There is a attribute called `android:spinnerMode` this is used to get the spinner in two modes as dialog or dropdown.

where as the attribute `android:prompt` is to get the spinner Title or Heading after opening it(in Dialog mode).

Answer (score 0):

Just try to this so you will get selected string:

```
String name = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```